# Calendar jumps to current month with jQuery multi date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, date

I am using a jQuery multi date picker in my html. When I am select the first date in date picker it works fine but when I choosing the second date it jumps to the current month but date picker value was append to input box.

I don't know what I've done wrong in this code:

```
$('#datePick').multiDatesPicker({
  beforeShowDay: my_array,
  // For disabling all "Sundays"
  dateFormat: "d/m/yy",
  maxDate: "+3m",
  minDate: "-1m",
  multidate: true,
  addDisabledDates: My_array,
  onSelect: function load() {
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Excellent question.**

I didn't find anything in the [documentation](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) to fix the strange behavior you noticed.
It really *looks like a bug* to me.

I worked on it and found a walk-around, using the `onSlect` callback.
But this implies to disable any show/hide built-in animation.
I don't think it's a big deal...

See [this **CodePen** demo](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/amrYPG/) where the problem is recreated and can be compared with this solution.

And, below is the easy to cut and paste code *(without all the console.logs of the demo)*.

```
$('#datePickTweaked').multiDatesPicker({

    // OPTIONS
    showAnim:"",                            // Disables the show/hide animation.
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, // No week-ends.
    dateFormat: "d/m/yy",
    maxDate: "+3m",
    minDate: "-1m",
    multidate: true,
    defaultDate:"0d",                       // Default date selection as of "today".
                                            // Needed to show the right month on focus.


    // The "walk-around" is HERE, in the "onSlect" callback.

    onSelect: function(){

        // Get the "datepicker" object.
        var datepickerObj = $(this).data("datepicker");

        // Get the "settings" object within "datepicker".
        var datepickerSettings = datepickerObj.settings;

        // Get the last date picked.
        var tempDay = datepickerObj.selectedDay;
        var tempMonth = datepickerObj.selectedMonth+1;
        var tempYear = datepickerObj.selectedYear;
        var pickedDate = tempDay+"/"+tempMonth+"/"+tempYear;

        // Remove previous "defaultDate" property.
        delete datepickerSettings["defaultDate"];

        // Add a new defaultDate property : value.
        datepickerSettings.defaultDate=pickedDate;

        // "Hacky trick" to avoid having to click twice on prev/next month.
        $("#datePickTweaked").blur();
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#datePickTweaked").focus();
        },1);                               // 1 millisecond delay seems to be enought!!!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer didn't work for me.

I'm no expert but it seemed like maybe the `defaultDate` format has changed from when this answer was given.

Anyway, this is what I did for anyone who comes here through Google like I did. I was able to keep the `showAnim` effect as well, it doesn't really look fantastic though when selecting multiple dates. I guess it's good to give the user that extra confirmation of their accepted selection though.

A lot of the above answer still worked obviously. I've mostly just changed the way the `defaultDate` is handled by giving it a different value which I obtained by calculating the difference between the current day, month and year and the selected day, month and year.

```
$("#inputID").multiDatesPicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
  minDate: 1,
  multidate: true,
  defaultDate: "0d",
  onSelect: function() {
    // Get the "datepicker" object.
    var datepickerObj = $(this).data("datepicker");

    // Get the "settings" object within "datepicker".
    var datepickerSettings = datepickerObj.settings;

    // Get the last date picked.
    var d = new Date();
    var dayDiff = datepickerObj.selectedDay - d.getDate();
    var monthDiff = datepickerObj.selectedMonth - d.getMonth();
    var yearDiff = datepickerObj.selectedYear - d.getFullYear();
    var pickedDate =
      "+" + dayDiff + "d +" + monthDiff + "m +" + yearDiff + "y";

    // Remove previous "defaultDate" property.
    delete datepickerSettings["defaultDate"];

    // Add a new defaultDate property : value.
    datepickerSettings.defaultDate = pickedDate;

    // Avoid having to click twice on prev/next month.
    $("#inputID").blur();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#inputID").focus();
    }, 1); // 1 millisecond delay seems to be enought!!!
  }
});
```

Full credit to Louys for his answer, I would not have got this to work for my project without reviewing his code above.